# Relative homology of ball and sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

What is the result of $H_k(B^n,S^{n-1}; \mathbb{A
})$ and in any book can i found the proof ?

And what about $H_n(S^{n};\mathbb{A})$ (sigular homology of the sphere )??

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You have the exact sequence $$\underset{=0}{\underbrace{\tilde{H}_k(B^n)}} \to \tilde{H}_k(B^n,S^{n-1}) \to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(S^{n-1}) \to \underset{=0}{\underbrace{\tilde{H}_{k-1}(B^n)}},$$ so $$\tilde{H}_k(B^n,S^{n-1}) \simeq \tilde{H}_{k-1}(S^{n-1})= \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} \mathbb{A} & \text{if} \ k=n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right..$$

If you do not know $\tilde{H}_k(S^n)$, you can use Mayer-Vietoris sequence in order to show $$\tilde{H}_k(S^n) \simeq \tilde{H}_{k-1}(S^{n-1})$$ by decomposing $S^n$ in two hemispheres.

Comment: $\tilde {H}$ is the reduced homology ?, i dont want to use the reduced homology !

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Why not? In any case that only makes a difference in low degrees, write the exact sequence explicitly and you'll find the same result.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late... (1 year later).

You can also use @Seirios idea inductively, i.e.

$$H_k(B^n,S^{n-1})\overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow}H_{k-1}(S^{n-1})$$

by useing $H_k(B^n,S^{n-1})\simeq \overset{\sim}{H}_k(B^n/S^{n-1},pt.)\simeq \overset{\sim}{H}_k(S^{n})$ (because $B^n/S^{n-1}\cong S^{n}$).

I think the basic idea can be found in Hatcher's book. But I can not remind which page...